# Is there a search operator to find questions asked by active users?

Tags: support, status-deferred, search

It's possible to [search](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for older, personally relevant, unanswered questions (or without accepted answers):

```
intags:mine hasaccepted:0 created:..6m
```

However, I'd like to exclude questions where the OP has not been seen for, say, 6 months (many of these people asked a question then never came back). Is there a search operator that could do that?

Comment: I think this is a question that might be better researched at [meta.se] where I suspect the answer will be to use SEDE.  I had a quick look just now for an existing query but the most interesting and partly related one that I found was [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/gis/query/73604/user-participation) that shows the number of active GIS users week by week since day 1 - even without graphing the data it seems that we continue to engage more and more users at our site.

Comment: Indeed, there is [exactly this kind of question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138343/search-options-limit-to-questions-placed-by-active-users) on Meta. No answers though.

Comment: I'm setting this to a status that indicates that it is deferred to the SE developers who can be communicated with via [meta.se] Q&As.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should participate in [Providing Search Option to Limit to questions placed by active users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138343/215590) , the question you identified, at the Meta Stack Exchange which is for all SE sites because, to provide the functionality you seek, it appears to need an enhancement that is wider than GIS SE.